# MultiThreading producer/consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, consumer, producer

I'm writing a basic producer/consumer threading code. I got most of it to work, but I'm having an issue with rand(). Or maybe my issues are deeper than rand(), and rand is only the tip of the iceberg. I don't want to do anything too complex, (none of the runnable or wait).

I have a global deque of integers that acts as the buffer. I allow the user to enter in the size and the limit of run times. 
I make the counter a static global variable. 
this is my producer:

```
DWORD WINAPI producer(LPVOID n)
{
  cout << "\nPRODUCER:The producer is running right now" << endl;
  int size = (int)n;
  int num = rand()%10;// this is for making item.
  while (buffer.size() > size)
    {
    }

  buffer.push_back(num);
  counter++;
  return (DWORD)n;

}
```

this is my consumer--

```
 DWORD WINAPI consumer(LPVOID n)
 {

   cout << "\nCONSUMER:The consumer is running right now" << endl;
   while (buffer.empty())
     { }
   int item= buffer.front();
   cout << "\nCONSUMER:The consumer ate" << item << endl;
   counter++;

   return (DWORD)n;


  }
```

in main-

```
 while (counter < l)
  {
     hThreads[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, producer, (LPVOID)s, NULL, &id[0]);
     hThreads[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, consumer, (LPVOID)l, NULL, &id[1]);

     waiter = WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);
   }
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
     CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
   }
```

My output is like this:
[image]

So it only generates 1 every time. Srand didn't work either. But it runs the correct number of times.

EDIT---
So I fixed producer and consumer to deal with the race condition:

```
  DWORD WINAPI producer(LPVOID s)
  {
     WaitForSingleObject(Empty, INFINITE);    
     WaitForSingleObject(Mutex, INFINITE);
     cout << "\nPRODUCER...." << endl;
     int size = (int)s;
     srand(size);
     int in = rand() % 10;
     cout << "THIS IS IN:::" << in << endl;
     while (buffer.size() == size)
     {
        ReleaseMutex(Mutex);
      }
     buffer.push_back(in);
     counter++;
     cout << "\nThe producer produces " << buffer.front() << endl;
     ReleaseMutex(Mutex);
     ReleaseSemaphore(Full, 1, NULL);

     return (DWORD)s;
     }



     DWORD WINAPI consumer(LPVOID l)
     {
        WaitForSingleObject(Full, INFINITE);   
        WaitForSingleObject(Mutex, INFINITE);
        cout << "\nCONSUMER...." << endl;
        while (buffer.empty())
       {
             ReleaseMutex(Mutex);

       }
    int out = buffer.front();
    counter++;
    ReleaseMutex(Mutex);
    ReleaseSemaphore(Empty, 1, NULL);
    return (DWORD)l;
    }
```

BUT the random thing still keeps acting up. It only keeps producing one number over and over (even when seeded).

Comment: So where's the synchronization?

Comment: If the consumer runs first without anything, then the producer kicks in, and then the consumer picks up where it left off. It depends on which on starts first

Comment: You have an unprotected race-condition on the buffer. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: But how does that affect the random number? I even tried seeding it with the changing counter. It didn't work.

Comment: Hint: You're using the consumer thread to print out the number that's generated in the producer thread. But your mechanism of transferring the number from producer to consumer is broken because of the race condition. Therefore using the consumer thread to print out the random number is not a reliable way to check if the random number generator is working. What's a better place to check if rand() is working?

Comment: I'm thinking where I made it-- in the producer.

Comment: What sense does that ReleaseMutex() inside the while loop make? ReleaseMutex() means unlock the mutex; If you unlock it, you should lock it anew, before you... unlock it again! I think your code does not (or "should" not) enter any of the two while loops, as it is protected by the semaphores (eg in the consumer thread the buffer.empty() condition should always be false, because you wait for the `Full` semaphore); or I'm wrong? Waiting on a mutex and releasing it, is a "critical section" mechanism - they should be called in pairs (put in there code that only one thread should enter at a time).

Comment: Can I do this without using Mutex at all?

Comment: If you have access to modern C++ consider taking a much easier route and using the standard library utilities for this: http://rextester.com/HEA2012 See also http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Can you try putting some diagnostic message inside the `while (buffer.size()==size) { }` and `while (buffer.empty()) { }` loops? If your logic and setup are correct, they should NOT be entered at all, as they are supposed to be protected by the semaphores. Other than that, the Mutex is fine (you are using it to ensure atomic access to the buffer) - you could have used a Critical Section, but no prob. And the problem with the `rand()` is quite expected, as (at least per Microsoft documentation) there is a separate rand() sequence for each thread (you create them again, so its re-initialized)

Comment: Thanks, I tried the messages inside the while loops- they don't show up. That makes sense about the rand. I need to make sure it doesn't go past the limit, but also not re-create the thread every time. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't make sense to create (and destroy) a thread to only create or process one number - the extra overhead just isn't worth. Plus your code (as is) has some quite apparent errors or misconceptions. These are:

- In the main thread you create the worker threads (in that while(){ } loop) but only destroy them once at the end, that is you destroy only the handles created in the last loop.
- As noted in my message, srand() is called for each number to be generated, and always with the same initial seed, so it's normal to get the same numbers.
- The while() loops checking whether the buffer is empty or full don't make sense, and should not release the Mutex.
- The operations on the `counter` variable are probably wrong. Both the producer and consumer threads increase it, and the main thread uses it to determine how many numbers to generate/print.
- In your initial code fragment, `counter` is a global variable, with more than one threads operating on it, so you should read or modify it in a thread-safe manner, not this way. You should use some locking mechanism, like a critical section or interlocked variable access.

---

My suggestion would be to create one producer thread (generating all numbers) and one consumer thread (printing all numbers), transferred through the buffer. For this, you will need the following items (you have already implemented most of them):

- A "Full" semaphore, counting the numbers in the buffer, initially 0.
- A complementary "Empty" semaphore, counting the empty items in the buffer, initially set to the buffer size. The "sum" of these semaphores should of course always be equal to the buffer size.
- A mutex (or critical section), used for accessing the buffer.
- A global variable, used for telling threads whether to exit.

I'm posting some code samples below. Not sure if they work, you may need to revise or debug them, but this is just for showcasing the concept:

```
// Global
#define MAX_BUF 5
BOOL bExit = FALSE;

// Main Thread
    Empty = CreateSemaphore(NULL, MAX_BUF, MAX_BUF, NULL);
    Full = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, MAX_BUF, NULL);
    .
    .
    hThreads[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, producer, (LPVOID)l, NULL, &id[0]);
    hThreads[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, consumer, (LPVOID)l, NULL, &id[1]);
    waiter = WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);


DWORD WINAPI producer(LPVOID nCount)
{
    int nItems = (int)nCount;
    // Initialize rand() seed - each run will be generating a different sequence
    srand(GetTickCount()); // May need to AND GetTickCount() with RAND_MAX ???
    // Generate nCount numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
    {
        if (bExit) return 9; // Aborted
        WaitForSingleObject(Empty, INFINITE); // Wait until at least one item empty
        // Lock the buffer and add an item
        WaitForSingleObject(Mutex, INFINITE); // Could be EnterCriticalSection() instead
        if (buffer.size() >= MAX_BUF)
        {
            cout << "\nInternal Error: Buffer-full Check Failed!" << endl;
            bExit = TRUE; // Tell all threads to exit
            ReleaseMutex(Mutex); 
            return 1; // Exit with Error
        }
        int in = rand() % 10;
        buffer.push_back(in);
        cout << "The Producer generated: " << in << endl;
        ReleaseMutex(Mutex); // Could be LeaveCriticalSection() instead
        ReleaseSemaphore(Full, 1, NULL); // 1 item added, update semaphore
    }
    cout << "\nThe PRODUCER produced " << nItems << " items." << endl;
    return 0; // OK
}

DWORD WINAPI consumer(LPVOID nCount)
{
    int nItems = (int)nCount;
    // Generate nCount numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
    {
        if (bExit) return 9; // Aborted
        WaitForSingleObject(Full, INFINITE); // Wait until at least one item in buffer
        // Lock the buffer and get an item
        WaitForSingleObject(Mutex, INFINITE); // Could be EnterCriticalSection() instead
        if (buffer.empty())
        {
            cout << "\nInternal Error: Buffer-empty Check Failed!" << endl;
            bExit = TRUE; // Tell all threads to exit
            ReleaseMutex(Mutex); 
            return 2; // Exit with Error
        }
        int out = buffer.front();
        buffer.erase(buffer.begin()); // Remove item from the list
        cout << "The Consumer ate: " << out << endl;
        ReleaseMutex(Mutex);  // Could be LeaveCriticalSection() instead
        ReleaseSemaphore(Empty, 1, NULL); // 1 item removed, update semaphore
    }
    cout << "\nThe CONSUMER consumed " << nItems << " items." << endl;
    return 0; // OK
}
```

Notes:

- The `bExit` variable is global and accessed/modified by more than one threads, but as this is always done within a critical section (mutex lock), there is no need for using another one, or interlocked variable access.
- The diagnostic messages (eg `cout << "The Consumer ate: " << out << endl;`), or any other kind of "processing" these data (or "working" on them) could have been placed **after** releasing the objects. This would be more efficient, releasing the objects earlier to the other thread(s). I've done it this way to better illustrate the sequence of events in your tests.
- If you set MAX_BUF to 1, numbers should be generated/printed one at a time, otherwise it can't be determined, but the items produced minus items consumed should of course never exceed the buffer size.